# C#, I want to use a variable to sort characters using string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am sorry for the answerer who will suffer from my poor English skills.

```
static void function(int numSpace)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(num, 16), numSpaces}); 
    .....
    .....
}
```

I want to use the value of the 'numSpace' variable as a value that specifies how many spaces to space when sorting strings. The problem is that only constants are possible. I want to set this as a variable in the Main function to set the number of spaces to be spaced through keyboard input.

How could this be possible?

To solve this problem, I tested by referring to several materials posted on 'stack overflow', but all failed.

I wrote this code to make this possible.

`const int num = numSpace;`

But I found out that this doesn't work.

Comment: Can use just use `string.PadLeft` or `string.PadRight`?

Comment: Are you looking for `PadLeft`? `$"{Convert.ToString(num, 16).PadLeft(numSpaces)}"` or `$"{num.ToString(x).PadLeft(numSpaces)}"`

Comment: An example that shows the expected output would be very helpful. Right now it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet I hadn't even thought of 'Pad.Left'. thank you!

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko I hadn't even thought of 'Pad.Left'. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you need is basically nested string interpolation (since C# doesn't have dynamic or variable width implemented), but you have to use the original `String.Format` method since C# doesn't support nested interpolation directly:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format($"{{0,{numSpaces} }}", Convert.ToString(num, 16));
```

NOTE: The space after the close brace for interpolating `numSpaces` is required because of string interpolation using two close braces as an escape for a literal close brace. Fortunately format items ignore the space.

Comment: This seems to be closest to what I'm looking for. thank you for your help

Comment: @LeeSeonghyeon: If you're *really* trying to achieve `string.PadLeft`, that's going to be much, much simpler to understand.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your question also helped me a lot in finding the answer. thank you ^^)b

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation feature is limited to padding to a fixed amount with whitespace only, so you'll have to pad yourself, remembering that a positive alignment right-justifies the string:

```
var padded = Convert.ToString(num, 16).PadLeft(numSpaces);
Console.WriteLine($"{padded}");
```